# How to check if an item is in a list of list of list

Tags: python

I would like to check if an item is in a list of list of list, for instance if 1 is in :

```
my_list = [[[-1, -1, 0], [-1, -1, -1, -1]], [[-1, 1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1]], [[-1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1]]]
```

I tried :

```
if 1 in my_list :
```

but it only works for a simple list.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
from itertools import chain

1 in chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(my_list))
```

Comment: is this will work for any level of list of list @SachitNagpal

Comment: No. Not for any level. What chain.from_iterable(my_list) does to the list is, reduce one level. [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]] will convert to [1,2,3,1,2,3]. You can check this by adding list() function ahead. i.e.doing list(chain.from_iterable(my_list). This will create new list and you can see what the function is doing.
Here, there are two levels, in the question, therefore, I have applied the function twice, to break two levels.

Comment: ok thanks,  also we can achieve this by,  flatten the list of list and then check

Answer (score 1):

To find items in a jagged list, you can use a recursion, entering searching nested list by calling the function over again or simply testing for equality for non list items:

```
def recursive_find(lst, item):
  for x in lst:
      if isinstance(x, list):
          if recursive_find(x, item):
              return True
      elif x==item:
          return True
  return False


print(recursive_find(my_list, 0)) # -> True
print(recursive_find(my_list, 8)) # -> False
```